# How to Replace by pattern with Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex, replace, pattern-matching

I have a text, the text contains char sequence which begins with # and ends with ="" characters. Between the # and ="" characters just exists alphanumeric characters, without space or ; chars.
I tried to find the specified sequence with the following pattern `#[A-Za-z0-9]+(="")`
My question is how can I replace the ="" characters with three question mark characters ??? in C#?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The correct way of doing what you need is to capture the part you need to keep and only match what you need to replace:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(s, "(#[A-Za-z0-9]+)=\"\"", "$1???");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%23%5BA-Za-z0-9%5D%2B%29%3D%5C%22%5C%22&i=%23abc%3D%22%22&r=%241%3F%3F%3F).

In the `(#[A-Za-z0-9]+)=""` pattern, the `#` and alphanumeric chars are captured into Group 1 and later are re-inserted into the resulting string with the help of the replacement backreference `$1` (also called a placeholder for Group 1). Since `=""` is a string of a known length, you may safely put three `?` chars after the `$1`.

If you have no control over the pattern and just need to replace the contents of the first group, and in case you do not know the length of Group 2 value (it is not the case, but let's generalize), you may consider the following approach:

```
var s = "#Abc=\"\"";
var result = Regex.Replace(s, "#[A-Za-z0-9]+(=\"\")", m=> 
    string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", 
       m.Value.Substring(0, m.Groups[1].Index), // Get the substring up to Group 1 value
       new string('?', m.Groups[1].Length), // Build the string of Group 1 length ?s
       m.Value.Substring(m.Groups[1].Index+m.Groups[1].Length,  m.Value.Length-m.Groups[1].Index-m.Groups[1].Length))); // Append the rest of the match
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

See [this C# demo](https://ideone.com/DmsCnv).